# Mat-toolbar content alignmnet

Tags: css, angular-material

I want to have content aligned to left and right in this example.

https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples

I want Icon on the left side, Text in the middle and username on the far right of the row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the below to accomplish this.

Move the `mat-icon` to the top of the container to put it first.

```
 <mat-toolbar-row>
   <mat-icon class="example-icon">verified_user</mat-icon>
```

Apply `example-spacer` class to the text you want in the middle.

```
<span class="example-spacer">Second Line</span>
```

Add the following to the `example-spacer` class in `toolbar-multirow-example.css`

```
text-align: center;
```

User name after that

```
<span>User Name</span>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tesmev?embed=1&file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.html

Comment: What is the most sophisticated solution if I want empty space 40 % on left, then a warning icon and then text and material button.